# jquery mobile - swipedown doesn't work on mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I fix the code to work on mobile?

```
<script>
$(document).on('swipedown', '#page1', function () {
        location.reload(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery Mobile only includes events for swipeleft an swiperight. For swipe down you will need to either detect it yourself or use another library like hammer js.

Comment: Add this code and then you can use your function in your question -- http://www.gajotres.net/add-swipeup-and-swipedown-to-jquery-mobile/

Comment: Tasos Anastasiou, I'm testing in WP8.1 IE but not working
on pc work well.